# Get value from a cell in DataGridView into a TextBox when using BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to populate some text boxes while clicking the next row on the `BindingNavigator`.

I can use for the first text box:

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

but I also want to get the info from cells 2 and 3 into `textBox2` and `textBox3`. How can I access these based on what row is currently selected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try This

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column name"].Value.ToString();
```

**OR**

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[Column index].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the current row use the `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex` property value.